# redshift data.frame not getting written

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I am able to connect to AWS redshift cluster using RPostgreSQL package; read tables, even create tables using SQL - dbGetQuery. However, if I try to write a data.frame as below (wher con is a dbConnect object into redshift, and newdf if a simple data.frame

```
dbWriteTable(con,"newtb",newdf)
```

I get following error:

> Error in postgresqlgetResult(new.con) :    RS-DBI driver: (could not
>   Retrieve the result : ERROR:  LOAD source is not supported. (Hint:
>   only S3 or DynamoDB based load is allowed)

I have tried multiple simple data.frames, while reading data.frame works writing does not. Hint tells me to use s3 for loading, which means I can process data in R but cannot write a data.frame back to redshift, unless i use explicit inserts. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? or if this is an inherent way redshift prohibits or forces you to use s3

Comment: This is due to the way RPostgreSQL::dbWriteTable works - instead, you'll need to create the SQL (CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO, ...) yourself and send it to the database.

Comment: Thanks Hadley. Creating a SQL and inserting is working. Assuming dbWriteTable not working in this situation due to redshift's non-standard (different) implementation of postgresql

Comment: Yes, postgresql supports `COPY INTO STDIN` where redshift does not (it only supports loading from S3 or dynamodb)

Comment: @hadley could you elaborate a little on your comment?  Are you saying you need to construct the insert statement as a SQL query?

Comment: @Zach yes, right. The way that RPostgreSQL uses to load data into postgres doesn't work with redshift

Answer (score 1):

I solved using RODBC package.

You need to set up an ODBC connection let's call it i.e. redshift_con. From R than you need to create a connection (i called it ch) using:

ch <- odbcConnect("Annalect DB", uid = "username", pwd = "**")

loaded my dataframe in R and runned:

sqlSave(ch, mydataframename, addPK = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)

And R creates a new table in redshift called "mydataframename". Is not really fast, I'll keep updated if I find and optimized method.

If you need more information see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html

```
################ SAMPLE CODE FOR TESTING ##############
install.packages("RODBC")
library('RODBC')
ch <- odbcConnect("redshift_con", uid = "admin", pwd = "********")
sqlColumns(ch, "public.r_test")
USArrest<-data(USArrests)
sqlSave(redshift_con, USArrests, rownames = "State", addPK = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
I'll post a comment on the process speed.
```

Hope it can help.

UPDATE

Good only for VERY small amount of data