# Writing Data from R to Redshift issue

Tags: r, postgresql, error-handling, amazon-redshift

I have been trying to push data created in a work space on R server back to Redshift. Using dbWriteTable(), I can successfully create the table, but the data are not being written to this newly created table and the following error is produced:

```
> dbWriteTable(con, c("schema", "table"), value = df,append=TRUE, 
row.names=FALSE)

Error in postgresqlpqExec(new.con, sql4) : 

  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or 
near "STDIN"
LINE 1: COPY "schema"."table" FROM STDIN
                                      ^
)
```

Notes on the code:

- 'con' refers to the Redshift connection, the code for that in generic form is as follows:

  ```
  con <- dbConnect(drv, host="host_name",
                   port="port_id",
                   dbname="db_name",
                   user="username",
                   password="password")
  ```
- I cannot give full examples with data due to restrictions on the data.

Originally, I thought it could be a permissions issue within the work space. But, I have found an extremely slow solution by creating the table using dbSendQuery() and then looping through each row of the dataframe I wish to insert into Redshift via another call to dbSendQuery(). This tells me the issue must be related to something other then permissions since I can complete the task inefficiently.

Any comments or proposals related to this error are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Addressed previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129698/redshift-data-frame-not-getting-written

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your client "R" application is trying to use Postgres `COPY ... FROM STDIN` syntax. "FROM STDIN" is not supported syntax for the Redshift COPY command, see [Redshift COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html).

Options you might consider are inserting row by row (as you were doing with dbSendQuery()), but this will be slow, or outputting your data to a CSV file that can be uploaded to Amazon S3 and from there loaded using [COPY with S3 as a data source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-s3.html) (fast).